# Can I see changes before I save my file in Vim?

Tags: diff, vim, preview

I use Vim.
I open a file. I edit it and I want to see what I've edited before I save it.

How can I do this in Vim?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Diff_current_buffer_and_the_original_file

> Here is a function and command to see a diff between the currently edited file and its unmodified version in the filesystem. Just put this in your vimrc or in the plugin directory, open a file, make some modifications without saving them, and do `:DiffSaved`.
>
> ```
> function! s:DiffWithSaved()
>   let filetype=&ft
>   diffthis
>   vnew | r # | normal! 1Gdd
>   diffthis
>   exe "setlocal bt=nofile bh=wipe nobl noswf ro ft=" . filetype
> endfunction
> com! DiffSaved call s:DiffWithSaved()
> ```
>
> To get out of diff view you can use the `:diffoff` command.
>
> Below is a similar function, adapted to mimic the `'cvs diff'` command...

Comment: Might want to give RCSVers.vim a try: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=563

Comment: @luc-hermitte Isn't the alternative `:w !diff % -` superior when you're using vim on an everchanging and large number of boxes that you can't easily change the .vimrc for? (Provided they have diff installed.)

Comment: If you are unlucky enough to not be in charge of your vim environment certainly. So far, wherever I work on, even for 2 weeks, I try to install a fully featured vim, and I have a tarball of 100+ vim config files ready to be deployed.

Comment: Vim is not the tool of the last hope. The one that will work when nothing else is available. It is my main working tool.

Comment: Just supplying a link is not really an answer

Comment: Chaos's answer is superior and in Tobias's answer, the explanation is complete.

Comment: Can you please add some content instead of just a link? SO guidelines...

Comment: Awesome. I added a `nnoremap <leader>d :DiffSave<CR>` to it. However, what is the recommanded way to go back to edition of the file?

Comment: Also adding a safeguad to avoid calling it while already in a diff mode would be nice

Comment: This is great, and even better with https://github.com/lambdalisue/vim-unified-diff

Answer (score 210):

```
:w !diff % -
```

Comment: Only works if diff is installed on your system (read: doesn't work cross-platform)

Comment: Is there a way to do this with vimdiff?  I tried :w !vimdiff % - 
 but without success.

Comment: Can somebody explain that? I don't understand what's happening. I understand you're shelling out to `diff`.  `%` refers to the currently open filepath.  Why is all this an argument to the `:w` command? Also, how does `-` get assigned to the contents of the working buffer? Is that automatic in vim, that the contents of the buffer (or maybe a specific range in the buffer) gets assigned to stdin for shell commands?

Comment: @NathanWallace: It's an argument to `:w` because we're writing the file to the command (on `stdin`).  In the command, `-` tells it to read from `stdin`.

Comment: @JoeJ: Take a look at my answer - especially the comment.

Comment: @JoeJ I have added another answer on how to view changes like in vimdiff.

Comment: I ended up using this `:w !meld % /dev/stdin`.

Comment: Or use `:w !git diff % -` for a colorized version, if you have git installed!

Comment: @Dergachev one more reason I like your command because it uses a pager for longer diffs.

Comment: @Dergachev I get the error `fatal: bad flag '-' used after filename` when I run `:w !git diff % -`.

Comment: `icdiff` is a diff tool on linux with all the nice settings set from start. Also colorizes individual characters when applicable : )

Comment: @Grayscale `:w !git diff --no-index % -` worked for me. But afterwards arrow keys stopped working in vim, I had to do `:!clear` to fix it.

Answer (score 163):

Because some people asked about an explanation for the command

```
:w !diff % -
```

Here is my attempt on writing a more detailed answer:

I am assuming that you are working on a system with `cat` and `echo` installed (e.g. almost any GNU/Linux, Mac OS, BSD and other UNIX-like systems).

The above command works as follows:

1. The syntax for saving a file in vim is:

   ```
   :w <filename>
   ```
2. The syntax for executing a shell command in vim is:

   ```
   :!<command>
   ```
3. Inside the shell environment issued by vim `%` happens to point to the current filename. You can verify this by executing the following:

   ```
   :!echo %
   ```

   This should output the filename (or an error, if vim was run without a filename).

   Using cat we can also output the content of the file:

   ```
   :!cat %
   ```

   This should return the files content in its last saved state or an error if it has never been saved.
4. The program diff is able to read from standard input (stdin). Its man page states the following:

   > [...] If a FILE is '-', read standard input. [...]
5. Executing the save command without a filename but rather a shell command behind it causes vim to write the files content to stdin of the shell instead of saving it in a physical file. You can verify this by executing

   ```
   :w !cat
   ```

   This should always print the files current content (which would have been written to a file instead).

Putting it together (or tl;dr): The file is "saved" to stdin, diff is run with the filename and stdin as input.

Knowing this one could also compare files with vimdiff doing something like this - this is just an idea you do not want to do this:

```
:w !cat > /tmp/tempFile && vimdiff /tmp/tempFile % && rm /tmp/tempFile
```

(Then open readonly and close vimdiff using `:qall`)

Comment: A more sane approach to use vimdiff would be creating a shell script containing the following `vim - -c ":vnew $1 |windo diffthis"`, making it executable, saving it in the PATH as for example `vimdiffWithStdin` and then comparing with the following command in vim: `:w !vimdiffWithStdin %`

Comment: Even simpler: `:w !vimdiff % /dev/stdin`. I don't know if a similar trick exists for windows.

Answer (score 14):

I've always likes [diffchanges](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2158) - nice, simple, works.

Comment: This works a LOT better than the more highly upvoted options. This gives the ability to toggle it.

Comment: @StevenLu - Meh ... what can you do? In any case, glad you like it. I find it more practical than the other approach.

Comment: Me, I do second @Steven, your suggested diffchanges is excellent. Thanks!

Comment: This can also be installed as a plugin from the same developer: https://github.com/jmcantrell/vim-diffchanges

Comment: nice plugin, but it doesn't delete the patch it creates afterwards? Edit: My bad! It does. I was using it the wrong way. I had to use `:DiffChangesDiffToggle`.

Comment: This is great! though how do I wordwrap the two split windows?

Answer (score 13):

from vimrc_example.vim:

```
" Convenient command to see the difference between the current buffer and the
" file it was loaded from, thus the changes you made.
if !exists(":DiffOrig")
  command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis
          \ | wincmd p | diffthis
endif
```

Comment: ...as documented at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#:DiffOrig. Advantage of this over `w !diff % -` is that it works over remote sources too (for example: `vim sftp://example.com/foo.txt`)

Comment: I like this better because we see the difference right inside the vim buffer itself instead of in a terminal

Comment: How do you go back to normal once you are done examining the differences?

Comment: You can get rid of the if clause by substituting command with command! (see :h E174)

Comment: @NikoBellic First close the "old" window (marked as scratch buffer) with ':q'. You can change between windows by tapping ctrl-W twice while in normal mode. Then you can toggle off diff by writing :diffoff

Comment: It's now on [`defaults.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/fb55207ed17918c8a2a6cadf5ad9d5fcf686a7ab/runtime/defaults.vim#L139-L146)

Answer (score 5):

git supports the following command

`:w !git diff --no-index -- % -`

map it to a command by adding the following to your  ~/.vimrc

`command GitDiff execute  "w !git diff --no-index -- % -"`

Now executing `:GitDiff` becomes a handy little command to quickly show the diff before each save.

Answer (score 2):

Source the following and use :DIFF command

```
function! s:diff()
    let tmpa = tempname()
    let tmpb = tempname()
    earlier 100h
    exec 'w '.tmpa
    later 100h
    exec 'w '.tmpb
    update
    exec 'tabnew '.tmpa
    diffthis
    vert split
    exec 'edit '.tmpb
    diffthis
endfunction
command! -nargs=0 DIFF call <SID>diff()
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you're looking for but [SCMDiff.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2201) is really cool. One keypress, and it diff-highlights your current file with the head revision in a source control repo. It's meant to work with many SCMS. I use it with perforce.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin, based on different answers here: https://github.com/gangleri/vim-diffsaved

It provides the `:w !diff % -` method and the more involved `diffthis` one.

Apart from that [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) allows this as well, but also much more (diffs between different undo checkpoints). Similar to [Gundo](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/).

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the [histwin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2932) plugin.

While it doesn't diff to the *current saved* version of the file (like the other answers), it can **vimdiff changes since you started edting**, and even **replay** your changes in order. The difference shows if you save intermediately.

Additionally, it displays a list of *all undo history branches* and allows you to switch or diff between them.

PS: While the plugin doesn't automatically track moments in the edit history since every file change, you can explicitly "tag" the moment when you save the file such that you can later vimdiff with it, if you want that. Maybe this could be automated?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use vim for comparison like in vimdiff, you could do something like this:

Edit your .vimrc and add:

```
nmap <F8> :w !vim -M -R - -c ":vnew % \| windo diffthis"<CR><CR>
```

From there on you will see your changes and can quit the diff view using `qall` like in vimdiff by pressing F8 in command mode. Replace F8 with any key you like.

Edit: Added -M to disallow any modification, because it is not save.

Comment: This command starts to work for me, it shows me the diff side by side. However, as soon as I try and edit anything the vim window goes crazy. I start typing and I get a bash prompt behind the words in vim on either side of the screen. So it seems to display the diff, but then vim crashes. Additionally, I get this error `Vim: Error reading input, exiting...` any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: @Trevor: I could only guess what the problems are. It is indeed not save to make any modifications while diffing like this. Hence I have added "-M" parameter to disallow it entirely. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Changes you just edited [**buffer**], i.e. those that differ from last saved version (in **working dir**ectory), these may differ with last index version (**Git**). I mapped both:

```
" Find diff inbetween currrent buffer and ... A{last index version} vs B{last saved version in working directory}
"  - A{last index version}: the file as you last commited it
    " git diff to vimdiff against the index version of the file:
    nnoremap <leader>gd <Esc>:Gvdiff<CR><Esc>:echo "currentBuffer vs lastIndexVersion (last commited)"<CR>
"  - B{last saved version in working directory}: the file you last :w,
"   not neccesary commited it (not commited for sure if it is in NO git project)
    " https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Diff_current_buffer_and_the_original_file
    nnoremap <leader>gd2 <Esc>:DiffSaved<CR><Esc>:echo "currentBuffer vs lastSaved (not neccesary equal to last commited)"<CR>
    function! s:DiffWithSaved()
        let filetype=&ft
        diffthis
        vnew | r # | normal! 1Gdd
        diffthis
        exe "setlocal bt=nofile bh=wipe nobl noswf ro ft=" . filetype
    endfunction
    com! DiffSaved call s:DiffWithSaved()
```

Example of vimdiff vs Gdiff.

- vimdiff:
  [image: :vimdiff]
- Gdiff:
  [image: Gdiff]
  Commiting changes, you see only Gdiff, what might, or might have same changes as vimdiff:
  [image: commiting changes, you see only Gdiff, what might, or might NOT have same changes as vimdiff]

Furthermore, to easy `vimdiff` homonym file in other path:

```
    " vimdiff homonym file 
   nnoremap <leader>dh  <Esc>:vsplit %:p:h/../__/%:t <bar> :windo diffthis<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
        "E.g."$ vim /path01/proj02_pg064/processorder.php
        ":vsplit %:p:h/../proj01_pg05/%:t | :windo diffthis
```

Comment: One could just make 1 map that executes: a `Gdiff` if possible and otherwise (e.g. not a Git project) then perform a `:vimdiff`. With `try-catch-endtry`.
But this way `:DiffWithSaved` in a Git project is lacked.

Answer (score 0):

You can make vim create a last backup and original backup with:

```
:set backup
:set patchmode=.orig
```

Thereafter, you can open them in a split:

```
:vsp %:p~ or :vsp %:.orig
```

And from there do:

```
:vimdiff in each buffer
```

If you're dead set on no leftovers but want vimdiff, you could also do:

```
ggVGy    # copy the whole buffer
:vnew    # open a split
CTRL-W w # switch to it
shift-P  # paste at start
```

and then do :diffthis on each split

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, that's what the 'changes' command is for:

```
:changes
```

[:help changes](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%3Achanges)

Answer (score -2):

Follow the above suggests I use git diff that I like much:

```
:w !git diff  % -
```