# VIM - Show the diff of last saved version and current unsaved version

Tags: vim, diff, vimdiff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I see changes before I save my file in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749297/can-i-see-changes-before-i-save-my-file-in-vim)

> Duplicate: [Can I see changes before save my file in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749297/can-i-see-changes-before-save-my-file-in-vim)

Is there a way to see the diff of the saved version and the edited version of the same file in VIM?

This is the scenario: I've opened a file, editing something and I went away from the computer due to some work. After sometime I returned back and I forgot what I was editing and I would like to see the difference between the last saved and the current unsaved version of the same file. Is there a way to do it?

Of course, I can keep undoing till the last change and start redoing to go back to my unsaved version. But what I would like to see is a diff.

Answer (score 40):

```
:w !diff % -
```

Comment: Could we get an explanation for this to make it easier to understand?

Comment: @Marlun I have written an explanation in the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749297/can-i-see-changes-before-i-save-my-file-in-vim/22360650) referenced inside the duplicate notification.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently :DiffOrig does the same thing as the custom function did a couple links deep into Mr. Golubyev's post. It may only be in newer versions of Vim by default, though.

Comment: wikia tips does a few other things regarding the options set.