# Validate PHP syntax in VIM

Tags: php, vim, syntax

I would like to know how if it's possible to validate if a PHP file is valid in VIM without closing VIM every time?

Thank you

Comment: Try https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic (previously https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) it's very good.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can execute shell commands in vim. This is the same as calling `php -l filename.php` from the shell:

```
:!php -l %
```

I have this mapped into my `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim` file so that I only have to press F5:

```
map <F5> :!php -l %<CR>
```

Comment: Note this will validate the saved file, so if you have unsaved changes, it won't see them.

Comment: Can we use a different key for mapping like: CTRL+P?

Comment: @Jimmy, I think it would be something like `map <C-P> :!php -l %<CR>`.

Comment: This just tests saved file, How can I test my current open file before saving?

Comment: Would appreciate a way to check syntax even if file is not saved, too. Without the use of a pluggin.

Answer (score 8):

Use `:make` with the following php specific settings:

```
:set makeprg=php\ -l\ %
:set errorformat=%m\ in\ %f\ on\ line\ %l,%-GErrors\ parsing\ %f,%-G
```

Your syntax errors will be in the Quickfix window. You can open this buffer with `:copen` or `:cope` for short. If you only want to open the window only if their are errors use `:cwindow`.

You can use `:cnext` and `:cprev` to move through the quickfix list to jump to the corresponding errors. I suggest Tim Pope's excellent [unimpared.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) plugin to make moving through the list as simple as `[q` and `]q`.

To simplify the workflow I suggest a mapping like this one:

```
nnoremap <f5> :update<bar>make<bar>cwindow<cr>
```

Now you can just hit `<f5>` and the buffer will be updated (if necessary), linted, and any errors will appear in the quickfix window.

To make this a bit more robust, add these commands to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`. Example `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`

```
setlocal makeprg=php\ -l\ %
setlocal errorformat=%m\ in\ %f\ on\ line\ %l,%-GErrors\ parsing\ %f,%-G
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <f5> :update<bar>sil! make<bar>cwindow<cr>
```

For more information:

```
:h quickfix
:h makeprg
:h errorformat
```

Comment: When I run this code, it works but makes the buffer completely blank.

Comment: The mapping provided will only write the buffer *if needed), lint via the makeprg, and then show the quickfix window if there are errors. It does not make any changes to the buffer in any way other than possibly writing it to disk. Is there a chance you are looking at a blank quickfix window?

Answer (score 3):

`:w !php -l`

The real credit goes to [Can I see changes before I save my file in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749297/can-i-see-changes-before-i-save-my-file-in-vim/22360650#22360650) for the idea so up vote there.

But to explain on this post (mostly taken from above):
The above command works as follows:

1. The syntax for saving a file in vim is:

   ```
    :w <filename>
   ```
2. The syntax for executing a shell command in vim is:

   ```
    :!<command>
   ```
3. Executing the save command without a filename but rather a shell command behind it causes vim to write the files content to stdin of the shell instead of saving it in a physical file. You can verify this by executing

   ```
    :w !cat
   ```

   This should always print the files current content (which would have been written to a file instead).

4 You can check code with `php -l` from `STDIN` by piping it in

The file is "saved" to stdin, php lint is run with the  stdin as input.

Answer (score 1):

To check PHP syntax without having to save first you can use:

map  :w !php -l

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Runtime_syntax_check_for_php

Answer (score 1):

You should try a plugin like [Neomake](https://github.com/neomake/neomake). It will show you in the gutter error markers for every PHP syntax errors. Go on the line to see the error itself. You can as well link it to [PHP Mess detector](https://phpmd.org/) and [PHP Stan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan) to show you errors and possible improvements in your code.

This combo is very powerful!

In case you are interested I wrote an article how to make a [Vim PHP IDE](http://web-techno.net/vim-php-ide/). This is basically a list of essential plugins you should try out! Of course Neomake is part of it.

Answer (score 0):

For just syntax highlight (what sometimes gives clues about errors) a non yet saved file (usually black and white on vim)  just source the syntax file:

```
:source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/[the syntaxfile].vim
```

Examples

```
:source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/sh.vim
:source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/php.vim
:source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/javascript.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually run the PHP linting commands, but if you're doing full time development in PHP then it's easier to use a generic syntax checking plugin.

[Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) (as recommended by [@lucapette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7272221/327074)) has long been the main syntax plugin for Vim with fairly relaxed requirements:

> Syntastic itself has rather relaxed requirements: it doesn't have any external dependencies, and it needs a version of Vim compiled with a few common features: `autocmd`, `eval`, `file_in_path`, `modify_fname`, `quickfix`, `reltime`, `statusline`, and `user_commands`. Not all possible combinations of features that include the ones above make equal sense on all operating systems, but Vim version 7 or later with the "normal", "big", or "huge" feature sets should be fine.

Since Vim 8, which allows for asynchronous syntax checking, there are now two good plugins. These work by continuously linting your code so you don't have to save your code for errors to show up:

1. [Asyncronous Lint Engine (ale)](https://github.com/w0rp/ale)
2. [Neomake](https://github.com/neomake/neomake) (as recommended by [@matthieu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634054/327074))

All of these should automatically call `php -l` for the current file as long as the syntax for that file is set to PHP (`:set syntax=php` if Vim doesn't automatically recognise the syntax).