# Show all local changes in vim file

Tags: vim, diff

I know that it is possible to jump to last change in vim, like this :

```
`.
```

*-- That is: a **backtick**, followed by a **dot**.*

I would like to know if it is possible to get a history of changes made or at least show last change made, not just jumping to it - *is there a way to use diff to help display changes?*

Also, how many changes is stored?

Comment: See `:help :changes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the changes by typing `:changes` or use the `:DiffOrig` after   putting in your `.vimrc` the command below to see the changes made to the original file:

```
command! DiffOrig rightbelow vertical new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis | wincmd p | diffthis
```

### Explanation:

---

- ***command DiffOrig rightbelow vertical new***

Create a new command named `DiffOrig` which will *split a new empty vertical window and move cursor to it*.

Now we have two buffers if you type `:buffers` or `:files` or `:ls` 
it will list all the existed buffers where  each one has a unique id number and a name:

**.** The current buffer (where the cursor is active) is called **%**

**.** The buffer where the cursor was previously is called **#**

- ***set bt=nofile***

Set the `buffertype` of the new buffer to nofile

- ***read #***

Put the content of the alternate buffer (original one) in the current buffer (%) (**after** the line where the command is executed) (the content will be the **last saved status**)

- ***0d_***

Delete the line to move the content one line up.

- ***diffthis***

Activate diff in the buffer in order to display the changes.

- ***wincmd p***

Move to the other buffer window (the command is same as `ctrl-w p`)

- ***diffthis***

Activate diff in this buffer too to display the changes.

Comment: it seems this answer is the best, especially the :changes which was what I was really looking for - thanks

Comment: any chance that you could explain in detail what this command is actually doing?

Comment: the command line you posted consists of several commands, I just wanted to know a bit more about how it is working

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this have already been answered in :

[see changes in vim before save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749297/can-i-see-changes-before-i-save-my-file-in-vim)

after adding following to my .vimrc :

```
function! s:DiffWithSaved()
  let filetype=&ft
  diffthis
  vnew | r # | normal! 1Gdd
  diffthis
  exe "setlocal bt=nofile bh=wipe nobl noswf ro ft=" . filetype
endfunction
com! DiffSaved call s:DiffWithSaved()
```

then I can use following command :

:DiffSaved

and I will get something like this:

[image: example of vim in terminal]

in example I changed F to f